# Tool to backup, verify & restore specified files on Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, backup, data-verification

I want ability to specify multiple named groups of files/folders to archive & encrypt at local hard drive. Absolutely necessary is a built in ability to restore backup at specified location & verify completeness and correctness (by comparing it to original files).

Maintained open-source project is strongly preferable.

Ability to create automatically running incremental backup would be great.

I am currently using backup ruby gem - it allows to easily specify what and how should be backuped. Unfortunately it missing ability to automate [restoring backup](https://github.com/backup/backup-features/issues/28) and [verify whatever files are backuped correctly](https://github.com/backup/backup-features/issues/29).

Restoration is fairly easy to do manually (especially with low number of separate generated archives) but lack of built-in ability to verify backup is not OK - for example recently large part of backup failed silently and I almost missed it.

"it is not duplicate" explanation - [Back-up tool to restore Ubuntu system similar to Time Machine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/602/back-up-tool-to-restore-ubuntu-system-similar-to-time-machine) and [Backup to external hard drive using linux (recoverable without installation of additional software)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/520/backup-to-external-hard-drive-using-linux-recoverable-without-installation-of-a) and other are not requiring "restore files at specified location" & "verify backup".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by verifying? Checksums to verify correct upload or deeper? Like "Is there anything in my mysql backup, etc". I also use the backup gem and it mails me if something goes wrong (in terms of packing and transmission).

Comment: I guess that checksum verification would be a good start. Maybe also checking whatever filesize is in an expected range (entire photo archive fitting in 10MB means that something went horribly wrong) and checking whatever files present in previous backup are still present. At this moment I am backuping solely to local drives so upload verification is not so important.

Comment: What about RSync?

Comment: RSync is diverse and complicated enough that it is usable in the same way as good library may be used to develop a program - there is no obvious and quick solution. Solution involving RSync would be OK, but "use RSync" is not much better than "use cp, tar and diff commands" and only slightly better than "you may write it in C++".

Answer (score 2):

The software http://www.freefilesync.org/ might come close to what you are searching. You could combine it with https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/ or an encrypted File System like https://www.cryfs.org/